# Synchronize entire class in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, mutex, iostream

Look at this simple logging class (only relevant parts here):

```
class Logger {
public:
    void log(string& msg){
        //lock for all instances
        cout << "[" << tag << "] " << msg;
        //unlock
    }
private:
     string tag;

};
```

What is the easiest way to synchronize the entire class (not instances) so that separate instances of `Logger` (in different threads) write to `cout` sequentially (not all at once) ?

Comment: Adding a `static` member of mutex type should do.

Comment: Make yourself a synchronized `std::cout`.

Comment: @Xeo what do you mean?

Comment: [Watch this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism), there's an example for a synchronized `std::cout` (towards the middle and the end, IIRC).

Comment: Mutex type member must be "static".

Comment: Do you need to?  If you use `std::cout << ('[' + tag + ']' + msg;`, you shouldn't need synchronization.

Comment: string concatenation per call? brr...

Comment: @Xeo: If you just synchronize cout (hence a single operator<<) then you might get very mixed lines. Synchronization should be done at a line level.

Comment: @sellibitze: How abot actually watching Herb's talk? You pass a functor that does whatever with `cout`, and the whole functor call is synchronized.

Comment: @Xeo: I actually already watched Herb's talk. I simply have trouble with my mind reading capabilities w.r.t. what you meant by saying "synchronized cout".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way, with a mutex:

```
#include <mutex>

class Logger {
public:
    void log(string& msg)
    {
        // Lock for all instances
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(coutMutex);

        cout << "[" << tag << "] " << msg;

        // Unlocking happens automatically since the lock
        // gets destroyed here.
    }

private:
    string tag;
    static std::mutex coutMutex; // Don't forget to define this somewhere.
};
```

Comment: this is nice. But does `cout` guarantee, that things pushed to it via `<<` will be printed/flushed in order in a multi-threaded app?

Comment: @Queequeg In C++03, iostream is not thread-safe (it might be, but the standard doesn't specify it.) In C++11, it is (the standard guarantees that there are no race conditions that would result in stream corruption.) However, the order of output is not guaranteed, unless you specifically synchronize it. So the short answer is: yes. If you synchronize, then `cout << "12"` in one thread and `cout << "34"` in another will never result in something like `1324` being printed.

Answer (score 3):

Short version: Write a synchronized wrapper, wrap `std::cout`, then use the synchronized `cout` to write.

Long version:

```
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
struct Synchronized {
  explicit Synchronized(T& t_):t(t_) {}

  template<typename Functor>
  auto operator()( Functor&& f ) const->decltype(f(t)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
    return f(t);
  }
// I could implement these, but I'm lazy:
  Synchronized& operator=(Synchronized const&) = delete;
  Synchronized& operator=(Synchronized &&) = delete;
  Synchronized(Synchronized const&) = delete;
  Synchronized(Synchronized &&) = delete;
private:
  mutable T& t;
  mutable std::mutex myMutex;
};


// in "sync_cout.h"
extern Synchronized<std::ostream> sync_cout;

// in "sync_cout.cpp"
Synchronized<std::ostream> sync_cout(std::cout);

// In "logger.h"

// #include "sync_cout.h"
class Logger {
public:
  void log(string& msg){
    sync_cout( [&](std::ostream& os) {
      os << "[" << tag << "] " << msg;
    });
  }
private:
   string tag;

};
```

(Stolen from [Herb](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism).  Any errors in the above are my own, not Herb's.)

For superior performance, the above link also includes a non-blocking asynchronous wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it:

```
class Logger {
public:
   void log(std::string& msg){
   //lock for all instances
   {  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_mut); // or std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_mut);
      std::cout << "[" << tag << "] " << msg;
   } //unlock
private:
   std::string tag;
   static std::mutex _mut;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use c++ 11 mutex

class CircularQueue
{
protected:
    int * data;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int size;
    std::mutex queueMutex;
public:
    CircularQueue(void);
    int dequeue();
    void enqueue(int x);
    void initialize(int size);
    virtual ~CircularQueue(void);
};



CircularQueue::CircularQueue(void)
{
    data = 0x0;
    head = -1;
    tail = -1;
    size=0;
}

int CircularQueue::dequeue()
{
    if(tail == head)
    {
        throw "empty queue!";
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);

    int result = data[head];
    head ++;
    if(head >= size) 
    {
        head =head % size;
    }

    return result;
}


void CircularQueue::enqueue(int x)
{

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queueMutex);
    data[tail] = x;
    tail ++;
    if(tail >= size)
    {
        tail = tail % size;
    }
    if(tail == head)
    {
        throw "overflow!";
    }
}

void CircularQueue::initialize(int size)
{
    data = new int[size]; 
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
    this->size = size;
}

CircularQueue::~CircularQueue(void)
{
    delete [] data;
}
```